# Windows 10 update removed the Wifi adapter from device manager

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I recently upgrade to Windows 10 and from then everything worked fine, until recently there was a Windows 10 update which removed the Wifi option from my machine. I could not even see the wireless adapter anymore. I used the system restore to revert back the changes and I got the Wifi option again. But now I am facing the same issue again. I don't want to go back with restore every time.

**EDIT:**

1. I am using DELL Inspiron 17R 7737
2. Wireless Adapter - Intel(r) dual band wireless-n 7260

Can anyone enlighten me what exactly is Windows 10 update doing to my Wifi adapter?1

Comment: seems like I asked this question in the wrong forum!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across the same issue. Here is what I did.

Opened the back panel of my laptop->removed the battery->Fixed the battery again in the slot-> closed the panel-> and voila, everything started working.

It has nothing to do with any drivers or any software for that matter. The problem was that when you close the lid and let the laptop sleep for a while, and then try to wake it up, somehow the wiring between the wifi card and other devices are messed up, and windows is unable to detect the device. May be someone more experienced in hardware and stuff can explain it better, but for now this solved my issue and might help someone else.